# Java: Sum series logical error- final sum printing for all variables

Tags: java

I tried write a program that should be printing iterative sums.

But the current code is instead printing the final sum for each iteration, and I can't figure why :

```
package sumseries;
public class Sumseries {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("i" + "\t\t"+ "m(i)");
     System.out.println("===================");
     int x=0;
       for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
        System.out.println( i + "\t\t" + series(x) );
       }
   }

  public  static double series(int i){
    double sum=0;

    for(i=0;i<=20;i++){

      sum +=  ((double) i)/(i+1);

    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

What is wrong here and how can I fix it ?

Comment: What is the output you are getting and what is the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing 2 thing wrong.

> 1. `System.out.println( i + "\t\t" + series(x)`,
>      Here you are passing 0 always to series method.
> 2. `for(i=0;i<=20;i++)` in series Method,
>      Here again you are setting value of i=0;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("i" + "\t\t"+ "m(i)");
         System.out.println("===================");
         int x=0;
         for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
            //Pass Value of i instead of x=0;
            System.out.println( i + "\t\t" + series(i) );
         }
    }

    public  static double series(int i){
        double sum=0;
        //Don't Iterate it Again for 20 times, Iterate it for i Number of value only.
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
          sum +=  ((double) j)/(j+1);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: @pumpin26 did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your method :

```
  public  static double series(int i){//The parameter is variable i
    double sum=0;

    for(i=0;i<=20;i++){ // You are again initialising i as 0;

      sum +=  ((double) i)/(i+1);

    }
    return sum;
  }
```

I have written comments adjoining the lines. So you would always get the same `sum` whatever you might pass as parameter to this method.